# put $LINE value instead of "$LINE"

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have a loop in the script below. It is not working as I want. I need to put the $LINE value in front of each column. While it puts "$LINE" instead of it is value:

```
cat list | while read LINE ; do
sed 's/^/$LINE\t/g' $LINE.alf > $LINE.joined
done
```

Comment: use double quotes for variable substitution... `"s/^/$LINE\t/"` and `g` flag is not needed as start of line can be matched only once

Comment: I tried does not work

Comment: doesn't work is too broad.. what went wrong? is there a error message? also, it would help if you give a bigger picture of your problem... why are you using cat+while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not expand variables in side of a single quoted `'` string.  Try:

```
cat list | while read LINE ; do
sed 's/^/'"$LINE"'\t/' $LINE.alf > $LINE.joined
done
```